# Ergibt und ergibt sich

Tags: meaning

I am under the impression that "ergibt" means "to give" or "results," in the sense of logical implication. I have seen it both by itself and with the word "sich."  I understand that "ergibt sich" means "giving one," in the sense that one now knows this result. But I do not understand what kind of situation calls for using "sich" versus not using "sich." Could someone please clearify this.

Comment: Note also: »sich ergeben« can also mean »surrender«: »Als die Polizei den Schützen stellt, **ergibt er sich.**« = »When the police put the rifleman, **he surrendered.**«

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Your translation mixes up times, and I'd use probably not "put" here.

Comment: @Robert Hubert probably meant to say "When the police cornered ..."

Answer (score 6):

It depends on whether the *result*, in german *das Ergebnis*, is the object or the subject of the sentence.

If the sentence has the form "A **ergibt** B", then the result, here B, is the object.

> Zwei plus drei **ergibt** *fünf*.
>
> Two plus three **results in/ amounts to/ yields** *five*.

If the sentence has the form "A **ergibt sich** aus B", then the result, now A, is the subject.

> Fünf **ergibt sich** aus zwei plus drei.
>
> Five **results from** two plus three.

Answer (score 2):

I try to explain it with an example:

> [1] Die Beobachtung von Vögeln **ergibt** interessante Erkenntnisse.
>
> [2] Aus der Beobachtung von Vögeln **ergeben sich** interessante Erkenntnisse.

In Sentence [1] »Die Beobachtung von Vögeln« is the subject and »interessante Erkenntnisse is the object«. In Sentence [2] »interessante Erkenntnisse« is the subject **and** the object.

Comment: I'll tell that to my wife next time she complains about me watching porn. SCNR. ;-P

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong about "ergibt sich". The "sich" part does not mean "one", which would probably refer to the reader, but it means something like "results itself", which in German occasionally is the way to form what in English would be an intransitive verb. Compare:

> I opened the door.
>
> Ich öffnete die Tür.

But

> The door opened.
>
> Die Tür öffnete **sich**.

The same happens with "ergeben", as other answers have pointed out already:

> Propositions A and B yield Proposition C.
>
> Sätze A und B ergeben Satz C.

but

> Satz C ergibt sich aus Sätzen A und B.
>
> Proposition C follows from Propositions A and B.